# Выдается ошибка Template does not exist (Django)

Tags: python, html, css, django

помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему. В программировании не профи, пытаюсь создать сайт (питон + джанго). Дошел до подгрузки шаблона, а он его не видит.
Бился об готовые ответы на подобную проблему, но ничего не помогает
Наверное, накосячил с директориями, но в упор не могу понять, где.
В первый раз задаю вопрос на стеке сам, если что-то не дописал - напишите пожалуйста, пришлю необходимую инфу. Помогите :(
Почему так много папок - пробовал в templates создавать папку одноименную с mainapp, как советовали на стеке в других вопросах, но ничего, к сожалению, не помогает

(settings.py)

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mainapp/templates/mainapp')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

(views.py)

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def test_view(request):
    return render(request, 'index.hmtl', {})
```

(Структура проекта)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4MtR.png

(Структура проекта поближе)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcHvm.png

(Ошибка)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmRF7.png

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\stud__project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\stud__project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\stud__project\stud__project\mainapp\views.py", line 5, in test_view
return render(request, 'index.hmtl', {})

File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\stud__project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\stud__project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
template = get_template(template_name, using=using)

File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\stud__project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 19, in get_template
raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /
Exception Value: index.hmtl

Answer (score 2):

структура папок проекта:

```
stud_project
    ....
    mainapp
        templates
            mainapp
                index.html
    stud_projects
        ...
        settings.py
        ...
    common_templates
```

если ты рендеришь

```
return render(request, 'index.hmtl', {})
```

тогда тебе нужно перенести файл `index.html` на папку выше и расположить в `mainapp/templates`, если же ты хочешь, что бы папка шаблоны располагалась именно внутри `mainapp/templates/main/`, тогда используй `render(request, 'mainapp/index.hmtl', {})`

так же небольщое замечание
обычно в

```
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mainapp/templates/mainapp')],
```

ты указываешь путь в котором будут храниться шаблоны, которые общие для всего проекта, без привязки к какому-то конкретному приложению, например папка `common_templates`, которую я добавил к твоему проекту.

Для того, что бы папка `mainapp/templates` так же была в списке папок которую джанго ищет при использовании шаблона без того, что бы указать ee непосрественно в `DIRS`, необходимо в файл `settings.py` добавить твое приложение в раздел `INSTALLED_APPS`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ...
    'mainapp',
    
    'app_1',
    'app_2',
    ...
    'app_n',
]
```

в итоге когда ты рендеришь шаблон `return render(request, 'index.hmtl', {})` у тебя шаблон будет искаться в следующих папках

```
stud_project\mainapp\templates
stud_project\app_1\templates
stud_project\app_2\templates
...
stud_project\app_n\templates
```

а так же будет исопльзована папка, которая прописана в  `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)],`