# Как сделать так, чтобы Django отдавал index.html Angular?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

У меня есть проект Django + Angular со следующей структурой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В папке application, я скомпилировал проект angular в папку dist. В папке dist - application есть index.html. Что мне сделать, чтобы Django выдал мне этот index.html, когда я запрашиваю, например, localhost: 8000? Я пытался манипулировать с помощью STATIC_ROOT, но у меня возникла ошибка `TemplateDoesNotExist`.

*setting.py* выглядит следующим образом

```
    ANGULAR_DIR = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))).split('client')[0], 'application/'
)

    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(ANGULAR_DIR, 'dist', 'application')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(ANGULAR_DIR, 'dist', 'application'),
)
```

*url.py*

```
 from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('auth/', include('authentication.urls')),
    path('api/', include('api.urls')),
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Решение, описанное тут прекрасно подошло мне https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51100877/how-to-properly-serve-my-angular-application-static-files-from-a-django-project

Answer (score 0):

index.html это не статический файл, это файл шаблона. Тебе нужно настроить

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [Тут указать путь, по которому ты хочешь искать свои шаблоны],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

вот тут я более подробно описывал как именно django ищет файлы шаблонов
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1236095/395792

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я попробовал 'DIRS': [os.path.join(ANGULAR_DIR, 'dist', 'application')], но все равно получаю ошибку

Comment: Есть мысль что нужно сперва править путь к базовой директории, иначе джанго просто не прыгнет выше неё